# How do I search file contents in Windows Vista and Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Vista Explorer, how can I search the contents of all files in a directory for a word?](https://superuser.com/questions/6325/in-vista-explorer-how-can-i-search-the-contents-of-all-files-in-a-directory-for)

How do I search file contents in Windows Vista and Windows 7?  I want to only search file contents (not file names) and I want to do this whether or not the files are indexed.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Agent Ransack](http://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack/). It can do this among many other things:

> Agent Ransack is a free tool for
>   finding files and information on your
>   hard drive fast and efficiently. When
>   searching the contents of files Agent
>   Ransack displays the text found so you
>   can quickly browse the results without
>   having to separately open each file!
>
> Agent Ransack provides compelling
>   advantages over similar search tools:
>
> - Regular expressions that allow complex rule based searches.
> - Immediate contents results view.
> - Various wizards to walk the user through the searching process.
>
> Agent Ransack is provided FREE of
>   charge for the benefit of the Windows
>   community. If you find it useful
>   please register it, free of charge.

[Windows Grep](http://www.wingrep.com/) is another great tool that does the job:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

WinGrep or Google Desktop

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I use [BareGrep, available here](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baregrep/).

Just from the screenies, I like it more than WinGrep, since it has all the search input boxes right there, to easily change without needing to click buttons and go to other input boxes or windows.