# search in source files

Tags: windows, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Vista Explorer, how can I search the contents of all files in a directory for a word?](https://superuser.com/questions/6325/in-vista-explorer-how-can-i-search-the-contents-of-all-files-in-a-directory-for)

I have a Windows7 and I need to search some mostly C# files for different text. Windows doesn't seem to search them. How can I search them?

Answer (score 1):

You'd use [TotalCommander](http://www.ghisler.com/). It has perfect build-in search tool.

Comment: I've tried it and it works, but it isn't free.

Comment: Actually there is only one limitation: annoying splash screen at launch. So in fact it is free :)

Comment: it is 30 days trial.